# What is the best way for a development NodeJS docker container to watch filesystem changes and restart on crash?

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemon, forever

Given a dockerized NodeJS based app, what it the best way to fullfill the following needs:

- To restart automatically the NodeJS app on a change in the source
  code
- To restart automatically the NodeJS app on crash
- To be able to stay attached to the container when an automatic restart occurs
- To be able to interrupt the running NodeJS app with Ctrl-C when attached to the container

I made some research and I tried the following:

1. Command: `nodemon -x node app.js`

Problem: the script does not restart automatically after a crash

2. Command: `nodemon -x (node app.js; sleep 1; touch app.js)`

Problem: the script does restart both on file change and on crash but the timestamp of the main file (app.js) is modified after each crash and that creates problems during rsync synchronization. And it's not an elegant solution.

3. Command: `nodemon -x node app.js` and `restart: always` docker-compose poicy

Problem: when attached to the container and the JS code crashes docker detaches from the container. It's necessary to attach back manually.

4. Command: `forever -w app.js`

Problem: Ctrl-C doesn't detach immediately from the container like in the case of nodemon. I think that forever does not forward the SIGINT/SIGTERM commands to the child process.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you rsyncing your code into the container, or is it a volume bind?

Comment: @JoshWulf Sorry I missed the notification about your comment :( It's a volume bind.